# How to set a single key binding for a sequence of commands in Emacs

Tags: emacs, emacs24

The Emacs manual only has an example to set a binding for a single command. How to do so for a sequence of commands. Specifically the following.

- [M-down] to [C-u 1 C-v]
- [M-up] to [C-u 1 M-v]

Which is practically single line scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution for defining key bindings for a sequence of command is
provided here below. Here's the summary:

- Create keyboard macros with names assigned

  - scroll-up-step: C-u 1 prior
  - scroll-up-step: C-u 1 next
- Bind the macros to key combinations

  - M-   <- scroll-up-step
  - M- <- scroll-down-step

You can include this code to your `init.el` file

```lisp
(fset 'scroll-up-step
   (lambda (&optional arg) "Keyboard macro." (interactive "p") (kmacro-exec-ring-item (quote ([21 49 prior] 0 "%d")) arg)))
(fset 'scroll-down-step
   (lambda (&optional arg) "Keyboard macro." (interactive "p") (kmacro-exec-ring-item (quote ([21 49 next] 0 "%d")) arg)))
(global-set-key (kbd "M-<up>") 'scroll-up-step)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-<down>") 'scroll-down-step)
(global-set-key (kbd "\e <up>") 'scroll-up-step)
(global-set-key (kbd "\e <down>") 'scroll-down-step)
```

Detailed Steps:

Start a Macro definition

`<F3>`        Start KBD macro definition

`C-u 1 prior`   The sequece of commands you wish to bind

`<F4>`         End KBD macro definition

Give the recent macro a custom name (no conflicts!)

`C-x C-k n scroll-up-step`

Do the same for the other custom command(s)

```
<F3>
C-u 1 next
<F4>
C-x C-k n scroll-down-step
```

Note:

prior = PgUp / fn+up (Macbook)

next  = PgDown / fn+down (Macbook)

Open the init.el in Emacs

`C-x C-f </path/to/init.el>` (usually "~/.emacs.d/init.el")

Append the macro lisp definition to the init.el file

```
M-x insert-kbd-macro RET scroll-up-step RET
M-x insert-kbd-macro RET scroll-down-step RET
```

Append the key binding for the custom commands to the init.el file

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-<up>") 'scroll-up-step)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-<down>") 'scroll-down-step)
(global-set-key (kbd "\e <up>") 'scroll-up-step)
(global-set-key (kbd "\e <down>") 'scroll-down-step)
```

You would notice that I have included the key bindings definition
twice for a single binding. This is because the binding is related to
the Meta key. The meta key is described as M in the GUI mode, but the
terminal still considers it as ESC (even if the alt/option key is
pressed). Thus I defined it twice so that it would work in both GUI
and terminal modes of Emacs.

This might not be the fastest method for defining key bindings for a
sequence of commands. But it certainly works. I wonder if anyone has a
more simpler solution (if any).

Comment: `(global-set-key (kbd "M-<up>") (kbd "C-u 1 <prior>"))` would be *simpler* -- but not necessarily *better*.

Answer (score 13):

You can use [keyboard macros](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyboardMacros) for that task. The link pretty much explains how to do it, for completeness here's what to do:

1. Hit `C-x (` to start recording a keyboard macro.
2. Do what the command is supposed to do (i.e. execute commands, hit keys, ...)
3. Hit `C-x )` to stop recording the keyboard macro.
4. Execute `M-x name-last-kbd-macro` to name the last-defined keyboard macro (i.e. the one you *just* defined).
5. Execute `M-x insert-kbd-macro` to insert the code of the last defined macro at point, copy it into your [init file](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html).
6. Put `(global-set-key (kbd "M-n") 'my-macro)` into your [init file](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html) (assuming you named the macro `my-macro`).
7. Profit!

Answer (score 3):

1. Find out what command (function) `C-v` is bound to: `C-h k C-v`. Answer:

```
    C-v runs the command scroll-up-command, which is an interactive
    compiled Lisp function in `window.el'.

    It is bound to C-v, <next>.

    (scroll-up-command &optional ARG)

    Scroll text of selected window upward ARG lines
```

What does `C-u 1` do here? Tells `C-v` to scroll upward 1 line.

So you want to call `scroll-up-command`, passing it an `ARG` of 1: `(scroll-up-command 1)`.

2. How do you define your own command that does that?

   ```
   (defun my-scroll-up-1-line ()
     "Scroll up one line."
     (interactive)
     (scroll-up-command 1))
   ```

   See the Elisp manual, node [`Defining Commands`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Commands.html).
3. And bind it to `M-n`?

   ```
   (global-set-key (kbd "M-n") 'my-scroll-up-1-line)
   ```

   See the Emacs manual, node [`Rebinding`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Rebinding.html).